# How do I create bootstrap like menus for React with TailwindCSS or styled-compenents?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, styled-components, bootstrap-5

I am just getting into React and want to either use `TailwindCSS` or `styled-components`. I really love the idea of `styled-components` through am concerned with the lack of pre built functionality that `TailwindCSS` has. Particularly the respnsive design `TailwindCSS` has built in (I come from a `Bootstrap` world).

With that said, how do I create a `Bootstrap` like hamburger menu. I want something like this for desktop and mobile.

**Desktop:**

[image]

**Mobile collapsed:**

[image]

**Mobile expanded:**

[image]

I am open to suggestions on choosing between the two style libraries. How do I create a menu like this for React apps?

Comment: If you used before **Bootstrap**, your choice is **Tailwind**, because styled-component you are writing plain CSS inside JS.

Comment: That's probably the way I will lean. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TailwindCSS with React with [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app).

However first I would like you to try something from your own .

You can find such similar examples at

- [tailwindUI](https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/elements/headers)
- [Flowbite](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/)
- [Tailwind components](https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/tailwind-css-navbar)

Comment: Wow flowbite looks cool. Never heard of that. I like the idea of styled components but the loack of built in things is tough. I worry about too much css in each element and leading to CSS that needs not to be there.